# Window width in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on theme development in wordpress where client needs two kinds of menus 1) Mega-Menu 2) Toggle Menu and client needs flexibility to choose which kind of menu he wants to show.

How to find window width in PHP.

Comment: You cannot get window width with PHP. You need to use Javascript and then send it over to PHP with AJAX.

Comment: I would have both menus available in the HTML and then use CSS media queries to hide one or the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish like below ways.

**1.** [ncurses_getmaxyx](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ncurses-getmaxyx.php)
You can check the size of current window by ncurses_getmaxyx.

*Warning:*
This function is EXPERIMENTAL. The behaviour of this function, its name, and surrounding documentation may change without notice in a future release of PHP. This function should be used at your own risk.

**2.** [get_browser](http://www.php.net/get_browser)
Try to use get_browser and check for *isMobileDevice* field. It might help only, of course, if the path to `browscap.ini` is set up in `php.ini`. If not, you can use php classes for example here.

Hope this help you.